# $getjson and booleans

Tags: jquery, boolean, getjson

I am learning jquery. I have a url which gives a json dump "/check_email_exists" which gives true or false. This is primarily HttpResponse of a jsondump.

How do I write a Javascript function which gives a true or false based on the json true or false.

I tried this

```
function ifEmailExists(email)  
{  

  return $.getJSON("/check_email_exists/" + email);
}
```

Obviously this is not working.What's the right way?

edit

I also tried this

```
function ifEmailExists(email)  
{  
    $.getJSON("/check_email_exists/" + email), function(data)   
    {  

          return data;  


     }
};
```

No Success

Answer (score 1):

From the `getJSON` doc:

> This is a shorthand Ajax function

AJAX is asynchronous (that's the first A).  This means that the result is not returned immediately.  If you want to do something with the returned data from `getJSON` you will need to use the other parameter, which is a success function.  This function fires when the response to the request is returned.  You cannot return this response from your function as it has not come in yet at the time your function completes execution.

If you absolutely have to block and wait for the response, you can use `$.ajax` instead of `getJSON` and set the `async` parameter to false.  This will force the call to wait for a response.  This is generally a bad idea so you probably want to consider if there's some way for you to get the same functionality using the asynchronous behavior.  Using `async: false` will hang the browser while it waits for the response.  If this response takes some time to come back, it will be a very bad user experience in most cases.

Comment: +1 for giving a warning about async requests and not just suggesting `async: false`.

Comment: I am beginning to understand what you are saying, but how do I get a boolean read through json, and then provide as a javascript boolean variable

Comment: In your 2nd example, the `data` returned in that function is an object which was represented by your JSON.  If that object contains a boolean variable then it can be accessed.  You would need to provide the JSON you are returning to get a more specific answer.

Comment: The Json is a simple Python django HttpResponse which does simpleJSON.dumps of either True or False.

Comment: Also I even tried wrapping the data received through getJSOn inside an eval, yet no avail

Comment: I don't think the eval is needed, I think jquery does that for you.  I'm not familiar with python django so I can't help unless you can give me the actual json generated.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Hi, my problem is exactly what you mentioned. I am returning a json object containing one of the field as boolean and I am unable to read that value. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("/check_email_exists/" + email), function(data) {  
    alert(data);  
});
```

When the data only retrieves boolean value, you should be able to get it like this. **This should alert True or False.**

If it alerts something like this `[object Object]` , then it retrievs a object with field names,  in that case you can use this `alert(data.exists)`, where `data` is object and `exists` is one field of that object.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function like this that returns true or false to you

```
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js">

function ifEmailExists(email)
{   
    var res=true;
    var result = $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url : "check_email_exists",
    data: {email: email},
    dataType : "text",
    async:false
    });
result.done(function(resp){
    if(resp=="false")
        {
        res=false;
        alert("Not Found");
        }
    return resp;
});
return res;
}
```

Make sure `http://localhost:8080/yourapp/check_email_exists` returns true or false